# Question about "si" clause with present verb

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

I came across a site which lists the types of "si" clauses. The one I'm confused with is "si" + present verb. It says the resulting clause will either be in the present, future, or imperative. My question is: can the resulting clause either be present/future? As in, can the two tenses be used interchangeably without changing the meaning of the sentence?

For example:

> Si j'ai le temps, je *jouerai* au frisbee le weekend.

vs.

> Si j'ai le temps, je *joue* au frisbee le weekend.

Do the two sentences have the same meaning? Is one of them grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

Both sentences are correct.

There is a slight difference in meaning. In the first one, the person will play freesbee during future weekends while the second one is about a custom that include past weekends too.

In the second sentence, ***si*** can be replaced by ***quand***, ***lorsque***, or ***chaque fois que*** without significantly changing the meaning while in the first one, only ***si*** is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

As Jiliagre says, both sentence are grammatical with distinct meaning. In the second sentence, *quand* would be more common than *si* if it's meant as a regular thing you do every weekend. If it's meant to cover only the coming weekend, the formulation would be in the future with *ce weekend* or *le weekend prochain*.